# torch.tensor object has no attribute 'dim' with a basic network

Tags: python, pytorch

I m having some issues with pytorch after I train my model, it seems that the type i pass into my network changes, i.e when i try to do.a single prediction my forward function has an error as it has no ".dim" function even though I pass a torch.tensor object as input. this is my basic network architecture

```
class Net(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self,input_shape):
    super(Net,self).__init__()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_shape,2)
    self.fc2 = nn.Dropout(p=0.2)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(2,2)
  def forward(self,x):
    x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = torch.softmax(self.fc3(x), 1)
    return x
```

it trains and works as expected on the training batch but when i pass a single tensor

```
torch.Size([1, 100])
```

it gives me this error

```
x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))  AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'dim'
```

The network was trained with batches of

```
torch.Size([64, 100])
```

And it worked during training on the batches of 64 and output the results I expected when when I perform a single prediction using

```
prediction = model(X[0])
```

I encounter this error. I have tried a few things such as printing the type to verify that it was a valid object being passed in but it seems that somehow during the forward pass the types I have passed become invalid and I cannot understand why if my input is a singular element of the original training data . I also tried wrapping the X[0] inside a Variable() as Im unsure exactly what pytorch seems to expect as input given this error. I have also read other answers but they seem to address changes mostly in other layers I am not using as returning different values and I am unsure how to verify if the output of one of my layers is changing the type passed into the next layer.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDITED------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-602-1f45fd5f7727> in <module>
---> 12 y_pred = model(X[0])

/opt/conda/envs/pytorch-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    487             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    488         else:
--> 489             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    490         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    491             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

<ipython-input-595-74840ffbc280> in forward(self, x)
     13     self.fc3 = nn.Linear(2,2)
     14   def forward(self,x):
---> 15     x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
     16     x = torch.softmax(self.fc3(x), 1)
     17     return x

/opt/conda/envs/pytorch-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    487             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    488         else:
--> 489             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    490         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    491             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

/opt/conda/envs/pytorch-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
     65     @weak_script_method
     66     def forward(self, input):
---> 67         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
     68 
     69     def extra_repr(self):

/opt/conda/envs/pytorch-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1348         - Output: :math:`(N, *, out\_features)`
   1349     """
-> 1350     if input.dim() == 2 and bias is not None:
   1351         # fused op is marginally faster
   1352         ret = torch.addmm(torch.jit._unwrap_optional(bias), input, weight.t())

AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'dim'
```

Here is my training batching also incase this is useful.

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader #Define a dataset and trainer for pytorch
class dataset(Dataset):
  def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.x = x.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True)
    self.y = y.clone().detach().requires_grad_(False)
    self.length = self.x.shape[0]
 
  def __getitem__(self,idx):
    return self.x[idx],self.y[idx]
  def __len__(self):
    return self.length

trainset = dataset(X,y)
trainloader = DataLoader(trainset,batch_size=64,shuffle=False)
```

EDITED------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

To add more details:

If i print(X)

```
tensor([[ 1.0430, -0.8477,  0.9932,  ..., -0.8662,  0.6748, -0.4958],
        [ 2.0728, -1.3987,  2.0863,  ..., -1.2584,  0.9423, -1.1652],
        [ 1.1594, -0.2600,  1.1863,  ..., -0.2268, -0.0596, -1.2434],
        ...,
        [ 1.2905, -2.1808,  1.2301,  ..., -2.4004,  2.1426,  0.8747],
        [-0.4722, -1.2714, -0.4748,  ..., -1.3785,  1.6691,  1.8886],
        [ 0.6362, -1.1497,  0.6117,  ..., -1.1174,  1.0634,  0.2901]],
       dtype=torch.float64)
```

and to actually train the network im using:

```
output = model(x_train)
loss = loss_fn(output,y_train)
predicted = model(X.clone().detach().requiresgrad(True).float())
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

EDITED------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

If i add the type passed into forward i get this during training

```
def forward(self,x):
    print(type(X))
    x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = torch.softmax(self.fc3(x), 1)
    return x
```

<class 'torch.Tensor'>
<class 'torch.Tensor'>

Comment: Put the whole starcktrace. The `builtin_function_or_method` suggest that this is not the issue with the Pytorch but the bug in the code

Comment: From what I see, it looks like `X.append` somewhere is putting the function in, like `X.append(fn)` instead of `X.append(fn())`

Comment: Ok i have added more details to hopefully provide more information

Comment: The error is at `self.fc1(x)`. So yes it's about how you get the `X`. If that part of code is not confidential then providing reproducible code would help

Comment: Or for example, `print(X)` before `trainset = dataset(X,y)`

Comment: Or maybe `model(trainset[0][0])`

Comment: Ok iv added those details, thank you again for the advice. The trainset[0][0] produced the same error.

Comment: What about `model(X[0].unsqueeze(0))`

Comment: Did you check that what goes in the input of `self.fc1` in the `forward` method of your class `Net` is a `torch.Tensor`?

Comment: I checked but i cant seem to get output when printing input_shape, only for forward function not for the__init__ so im unsure what fc1 receives.

Comment: I don't know which IDE you are using, but you could try to put a breakpoint on the line `x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))` and run your prediction script in debug mode. Then, you could check the type of `x`, and ensure that it is a `torch.Tensor` with a `dim` attribute.

Comment: Be careful, in your last edit you checked the type of `X` (capital) instead of `x` (the actual input of the method).

Comment: When i debugged input_shape, i found the input was {int} 100 but the input to the forward function x was the tensor i expected, even during training this was the case.